# Cannot import custom go module

Tags: go, module

Here is my main file (server.go):

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "routes"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", routes.Handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

My routes module is in the same directory:

```
package routes

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // stuff...
}
```

When I run `go run server.go` I get this error:

```
server.go:6:5: cannot find package "routes" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/routes (from $GOROOT)
    ~/server/src/routes (from $GOPATH)
```

When I place the code in `routes.go` into my `server.go` file, it runs fine. I cannot import the module. I have tried setting the `$GOPATH` variable to my current directory, I've tried rearranging my project directory to mimic the one [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). I'm running out of options. It is strange that a language with such wide adoption has such poor documentation on how to do something that is relatively easy in almost every other language. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

## UPDATE:

This is the output of `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/me/server"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: A packages named `routes` must be in the directory `~/server/src/routes`. You can't have multiple packages in a single directory.

Comment: Also read: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces in full - import paths are covered here (via golang.org -> Docs).

Comment: This sounds absurd to me. Why does go enforce an arbitrary project structure?

Comment: It makes it easier to reason about others's code: for any given directory, you can know that all Go source code within it is the same package. There's rarely deeply nested directories with hundreds of single-file modules in Go.

Comment: @dopatraman The Go Programming Language does not enforce any structure.  You can choose to run the compilers and linkers directly with any file structure you want.  The Go Tool does impose structure so it can do its job with no configuration expect the path to the workspace.

Comment: Read [golang.org/doc/code.html](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). The document covers the scenario you are asking about.

Comment: why was this downvoted??????? The golang docs are piss poor in this regard. thats why i had to resort to SO.

Comment: @dopatraman: what isn't clear in the documentation that people have linked to? [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) explains exactly how GOPATH is structured, and how to structure your project to work with the Go tools.

Comment: I don't think the question should be downvoted, but the Go docs are actually very good in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the routes package to `/Users/me/server/src/routes` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

The "[How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)" article is the recommended starting point right on the [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) page which explains this. (thanks @elithrar)

Peter Bourgon has a [good write up](https://peter.bourgon.org/go-in-production/#repository-structure) on well structured Go applications.

You should either have the `routes` package in a `routes` folder, or if your main package is in the routes folder you can have a `lib` folder within that folder with your actual `routes` package.

The reason for the folder structure is due to how go `import` statements work.  It would be ambiguous to enable multiple packages in the same folder given the way imports work.

Comment: Why does the go compiler look for a `src` directory? The error i got mentioned ` ~/server/src/routes`

Comment: Your `GOPATH` is likely set to `~/server`.

Comment: If you paste the exact error message I might be able to elaborate... it sounds like your GOPATH is set to `~/server` maybe? or `.`

Comment: yes, but if thats the case, why does it look for `src/`?? Also, how would placing my module in a `routes/` directory solve the problem if the compiler looks for a `src/` dir at the top level?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `go env` ?